# How to convert string into a list of integers in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I convert a string of digits to a list of integers ? I want "1234" to be converted to list 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a string to a list of chars with `string->list`. Eg.

```scm
(string->list "1234") ; ==> (#\1 #\2 #\3 #\4)
```

You can convert a char to it's ascii value with `char->integer`. Eg.

```scm
(char->integer #\1) ; ==> 49
```

The Ascii values for `#\0` ... `#\9` are in ascending order so you can substract to get the digit value:

```scm
(- (char->integer #\1) 48) ; ==> 1
```

Create a procedure where you combine these with `map` and you are good to go.

```scm
(define (number-string->number-list str)
  (map (lambda (ch) 
         <??>)
       (string->list str)))

(number-string->number-list "1234") ; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```